# JavaFX: How to extends Rectangle and add an OnMouseClick() handler

Tags: events, javafx, extends, rectangles, mouseclick-event

I want to track how many times a Rectangle is clicked. I decided to extend `Rectangle` class and add an `int` variable:

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class MyRectangle extends Rectangle{
    public int clickedTimes = 0;
    public MyRectangle(int w, int h, Color c) {
        super (w, h, c);
    }   
}
```

and in the main class i do this:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    GridPane root = new GridPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root.setVgap(1);
        root.setHgap(1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setPercentWidth(10);
        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        rc.setPercentHeight(10);
        root.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        root.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
            root.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
            for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
                int w = (int) root.getWidth() / 10;
                int h = (int) root.getHeight() / 10;
                final MyRectangle rec;
                if ((r + c) % 2 == 0) {
                    rec = new MyRectangle(w, h, Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    rec = new MyRectangle(w, h, Color.BEIGE);
                }
                ((Rectangle)rec).setOnMouseClicked(new Listner(rec)); //****QUESTION IS IN THIS LINE****
                root.add(rec, c, r);
            }
        }

        primaryStage.show();
    }
ram args the command line arguments

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The question is: Why do I have to cast `rec` to `(Rectangle)rec` in order to get the methiod `onMouseClicked()` ? MyRectangle should have all methods from the original `Rectangle` class

Comment: How have you decided that you have to cast?

Comment: Hm, it's wired. Now it works. By the way I got the error messagge like "onMouseClicked not found in rec".